# Not able to install shinytest

Tags: r

I am facing some problem while installing shinytest in my laptop. Getting below error message. Can anyone help me here?

```
> install.packages("shinytest")
Installing package into ‘E:/Users/AAAA/BBB/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘desc’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘png’, ‘rematch2’, ‘processx’, ‘curl’, ‘pkgload’, ‘praise’, ‘showimage’, ‘debugme’, ‘parsedate’, ‘pingr’, ‘callr’, ‘httr’, ‘testthat’, ‘webdriver’, ‘rstudioapi’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
ps     1.3.0  1.3.2              TRUE
callr  3.4.1  3.4.2             FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some dependencies ('ps', 'callr') may be out of date. 
Try running `update.packages()` before installing 'shinytest'.

Alternatively, you may try to install all the listed dependencies on by one ('ps', 'desc', 'pkgbuild', 'png',...)